# Make Android layout buttons into squares

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button, android-layout-weight

I am having some issues with Android layouts. On one of my screen I would like to have the four buttons as squares, with two side-by-side and the other two straight underneath. I looked on another thread on how to make that happen, but when I did what was said, it turned into a complete mess and did not work at all.

Here is what my current screen looks like:

[image]

Here is my current xml code that makes this screen:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PedometerActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pedometerRecommendationTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/recommendation_pedometer"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometerChronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chronometer" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp" >



</TableRow>

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/resetButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
  android:layout_span="4"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="@string/reset_steps_button_pedometer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startPedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_button_pedometer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pausePedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pause_button_pedometer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishPedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/finish_button_pedometer" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stepsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_span="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="---"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seek_bar_pedometer" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:max="20"
        android:layout_span="4" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sensitivityTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span ="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/sensitivity_bar_pedometer" />

 </TableLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each pair of the `buttons` with `LinearLayout` horizontally oriented and then the 2 `LinearLayouts` should be also wraped with parent `LinearLayout` vertically oriented:

```
<!- your TableRow above ->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resetButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_span="4"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/reset_steps_button_pedometer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startPedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/start_button_pedometer" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pausePedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/pause_button_pedometer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishPedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/finish_button_pedometer" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!- your TextViews below ->
```

Here is the result (*for the screenshot I just centered buttons and changed their background color*):

[image]

Regarding *the four buttons as squares* you can:

**1.** *Use equal fixed size for `button's width and height`* (in this case you shouldn't use `android:layout_weight` attribute). For example

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishPedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="@string/finish_button_pedometer" />
```

Note that when the `button` size is fixed make sure the text of the `buttons` isn't getting cut off. Also you could use different size value dependent of screen size. To do so define the values for each `/res/values-xxx` folder and them like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishPedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:text="@string/finish_button_pedometer" />
```

**2.** *Use a square image as backgroud for the `buttons`*. Create images of equal width and height with different `dpi` for each `/res/drawable-xxx` folder of the project.